# using pointer to an array

Tags: c, malloc

currently, I'm facing a problem with my code and my understanding of pointer. here's the code

```
struct command
{
    int type;
    int *input;
    int *output;
    union{
        struct command *command[2];
        char **word;
    }u;
 };
```

to my understanding, the instance struct command *command[2] is an array of pointer to array of command. So I allocate the array with these:

```
cur_command->u.command[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct command[2]));
```

So it give me a 2d array of command. However my teacher told me that struct command *command[2] is a pointer to an array command size 2. So `cur_command->u.command[0]` give the first command element instead of a pointer to a command array size two. My question is, how can I allocate the memory to develop this kind of behavior. thx

Comment: http://cdecl.org is really useful for things like this. basically what you have is an array of size 2 of *pointers* to struct command

Comment: You and your teacher are both wrong.  `command` is an array of two pointers to `struct command`.

Comment: @Carl Norum so, I can't setting the value of cur_command->u.command[0] directly without allocating memory right?

Comment: Yes, you can set it directly, it just probably doesn't do what you want it to do.  Your use case is pretty confusing.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm trying to do "cur_command->u.command[0] = //some other struct command" However, the pointer thing in the union confuse me

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest changing the name of the one variable to, e.g. `cmd` instead of `command` to reduce confusion. That is:

```
....
union{
    struct command *cmd[2];
    char **word;
}u;
....
```

Now, as a couple other comments have pointed out, `cur_command->u.cmd` is an array of two pointers to `struct command`. `cur_command->u.cmd[0]` is the first of the two pointers, and `cur_command->u.cmd[1]` is the second. In order to use either of them, they should be initialized to be pointers to actual `struct command` objects:

```
cur_command->u.cmd[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct command));
cur_command->u.cmd[1] = malloc(sizeof(struct command));
```

Then, you can use either one in the same way you use your `cur_command`, which is also a pointer to `struct command`. That is, you can set some of the fields:

```
cur_command->u.cmd[0]->type = 1;
....
```

Don't forget to free memory when you're done with it:

```
free(cur_command->u.cmd[0]);
free(cur_command->u.cmd[1]);
```

Since the structure is recursive, you may need some recursive code to correctly free all the memory, depending on how deeply you chain these things together...

Also note, that in your posted code (`malloc(sizeof(struct command[2]))`), the `sizeof(...)` bit isn't doing what you think it is. I'm not entirely sure it should even compile, as you can't treat a `struct` as an array like that...